# Create custom fields from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, custom-type

I have an export of a previous Wordpress website. Unfortunately I haven't aymore the site structure with custom post types and custom fields, so I'm trying to recreate it from the XML (created using the native wordpress export option).

I'm able to recreate the custom post type and import the contents, but the custom fields is a little bit harder.

The XML row with this fields is something like:

```
<wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>program_info</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[s:190:"a:5:{s:22:"difficulty";s:5:"hard";s:18:"type";s:8:"coding";s:14:"time";s:2:"50";s:21:"duration";s:2:"10";s:19:"total";i:60;}";]]></wp:meta_value></wp:postmeta>
```

But if i do create the fields "difficulty", "type", "time" and "total" the values are not imported correctly. I even already know the kind of field, for instance "difficulty" and "type" are select, while "total" and "time" are text boxes.

Comment: You still have a copy of previous version?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I only have the .xml file. I'm starting to recreate it from a blank Wordpress installation. Honestly I only care for the contents that "theoretically" I should be able to retrieve from the .xml once I will be able to recreate the custom post type structure.